# Segmentation fault when creating a thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, thread-synchronization

I'm trying to implement a class that creates a thread, increments a value and sends it to another thread, which number is defined as (value * value) % number of threads

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>

pthread_mutex_t m = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t cv = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
volatile int counter = 0;
volatile int maxval = 0;
volatile int next = 0;

extern "C" void *func(void *p);

class Worker {
private:
    pthread_t thread = 0;
    int nth = 0;
    int nproc = 0;
public:
    Worker () {};
    Worker(int _nproc, int _nth) {
        nth = _nth;
        nproc = _nproc;
    };
    void start() {
        pthread_create(&thread, NULL, func, NULL); // Line 27

    };
    void wait() {
        while (nth != next) {
            pthread_cond_wait(&cv, &m);
        }
    };
    void notify() {
        pthread_cond_broadcast(&cv);
    };
    void run() {
        while (counter != maxval) {
            pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
            Worker::wait();
            if (counter != maxval) {
                printf("%d %d\n", nth, counter);
                ++counter;
            }
            next = (counter * counter) % nproc;
            Worker::notify();
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);
        }
    };
    void join() {
        pthread_join(thread, NULL);
    }
};

extern "C" void *func(void *p) {
    Worker *w = reinterpret_cast<Worker*>(p);
    w->run();
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int nthreads = atoi(argv[1]);
    maxval = atoi(argv[2]);
    std::vector<Worker> workers;
    for (int i = 0; i != nthreads; ++i) {
        workers.push_back(Worker(nthreads, i));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i != workers.size(); ++i) {
        workers[i].start();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i != workers.size(); ++i) {
        workers[i].join();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Can't check if the algorithm is correct since I get a **Segmentation Error** when I call **pthread_create** (line 27)

This is what gdb said:

```
#0  0x0000000000400f5a in Worker::wait (this=0x0) at ht19-4.cpp:30
#1  0x0000000000400fd5 in Worker::run (this=0x0) at ht19-4.cpp:40
#2  0x0000000000400d26 in func (p=0x0) at ht19-4.cpp:57
#3  0x00007ffff76296aa in start_thread (arg=0x7ffff6f4f700)
    at pthread_create.c:333
#4  0x00007ffff735eeed in clone ()
    at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:109
```

Could anyone explain what exactly happens in this function please? How do I implement this correctly?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I think it is above the main.

Comment: Based on your stack trace it appears that your crash is inside something `func()` is calling. The entry `Worker::run (this=0x0)` suggests you've got an uninitialized object pointer; how are you initializing it?

Comment: It's nice to see some gdb in a C++ question. :)

Comment: Let the experts do the heavy lifting. Use `std::thread`.

Answer (score 2):

You're `func` doesn't handle `NULL` being passed in and the 4th argument of `pthread_create` is what gets sent the function in the third argument.

Change `func` to properly handle `NULL` and you should be good:

```
extern "C" void *func(void *p) {
    if (NULL == p)
        return NULL;
    Worker *w = reinterpret_cast<Worker*>(p);
    w->run();
    return NULL;
}
```

Also, +1 for posting gdb output so here's some more information:

If we follow your stack trace upwards (I'm typing them in the order they happen) we see that func does its job of casting and calling `run` on the `Worker` it casted from `NULL`.  Notice the `(p=0x0)` and `(this=0x0)`:

```
#2  0x0000000000400d26 in func (p=0x0) at ht19-4.cpp:57
#1  0x0000000000400fd5 in Worker::run (this=0x0) at ht19-4.cpp:40
```

`Worker::run` works fine because it only accesses `counter`, `maxval`, and `m` before getting to `Worker::wait()`

```
#0  0x0000000000400f5a in Worker::wait (this=0x0) at ht19-4.cpp:30
```

In `Worker::wait()` you are accessing `nth` which is a member of the null `Worker` instance and you finally get your segfault.

Comment: Yep, that would do it!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is while creating thread you are passing `NULL` for last argument.

```
pthread_create(&thread, NULL, func, NULL);
```

While the thread is started it calls **`func()`** with `NULL` value passed to it.
So inside **`func()`** *`p` is `NULL`* and you are trying to cast and then access that memory location. That's why you're getting segmentation fault.